# Something wrong with using openpyxl to set the cell style

Tags: python, openpyxl

I want to draw a picture using excel, and here is my program:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill, Color, Font

b = cv2.imread('D:\DeepLearning\image\memeda2.png')
b = b[:, :, ::-1]

def rgb_to_hex(rgb):
    return '%02x%02x%02x' % rgb

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
for i in range(1, b.shape[0]+1):
    for j in range(1, b.shape[1]+1):
        ws.row_dimensions[i].height = 17.1
        ws.column_dimensions[get_column_letter(j)].width = 3.0
        ws['%s%s' % (get_column_letter(j), i)].fill = PatternFill(start_color=rgb_to_hex(tuple(b[i-1, j-1])), end_color=rgb_to_hex(tuple(b[i-1, j-1])), fill_type='solid')

wb.save('memeda2.xlsx')
```

For some pictures it works well, but fir others it doesn't. I can't open these excels with correct styles, usually they hadn't been colored.
Sorry for my poor English, any suggestions may help.

Comment: Please provide specific example of which cells work and which don't. ie. The relevant colour values what you expect and what you're seeing. Also, I suggest you use `ws.cell()` to manipulate the cells using numerical indices.

Comment: @Charlie Clark This program can generate an excel，but when I open it , it said that ''some content is found to have problems, whether to try to recover?''.And if I choose yes , it comes to ''Deleted Features: Format of the /xl/styles.xml section (style)'' . How can I avoid this? Thanks for help.

Comment: Your post is therefore incomplete and inaccurate. There is probably a problem with the fills you're creating but without a file there is not a lot that I can do. I suggest you redirect the question together with a sample file to the mailing list.

Comment: Thanks Charlie. I guess that is not a question of openpyxl module or python but a question of excel, because I found that I can't set the cells to more than 65536 colors. So the program works well on small graphs, but big pictures with complex colors it will not work. I am new to Stackoverflow ,thank you in good faith for your reply.

Comment: What do you mean by 65536 colours? Presumably you mean the number of fills? The standard says these are unlimited but the implementer notes that "Excel limits the occurrences of this element to be at least 1 and at most 65430."

Comment: Sorry, I did not have a precise test, but the number of excel's cell style seems to have a limit. I can not fill the form with 65536 colors，while 65280 is okay. Maybe 65430 is the exact number. So my idea using excel to draw a picture is quite impossible.

Comment: Is that what you're trying to do? Yes, that won't work. You could, of course, create a drawing that does that.